# CoreOS EnvironmentFile directive failing

Tags: vagrant, systemd, coreos

I am attempting to start gliderlabs/registrator and have it connect to consul on the COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4 ip address.

```
[Unit]
Description=registrator
After=consul-server@%i.service
Requires=consul-server@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill registrator
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm registrator
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull gliderlabs/registrator
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net=host --hostname ${HOSTNAME} --name=registrator gliderlabs/registrator:latest consul://${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:8500

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop registrator

[X-Fleet]
#Global=true
```

I am running into an error on starting the service that complains about the EnvironmentFile directive.

`Dec 13 16:23:41 core-01 systemd[1]: [/run/fleet/units/registrator.service:5] Unknown lvalue 'EnvironmentFile' in section 'Unit`'

I am currently running coreos 835.9.0.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be failing?

Answer (score 0):

The unit provided does not match up with what the error is returning. The error is essentially saying that the `EnvironmentFile=`option is in the `[Unit]` section of your systemd-unit, and that the option isn't valid within that section.

Either what you actually have in the unit is different from what you put here, or it's possible fleet messed it up when it parsed and rendered out the unit.

If you look at the file in `/run/fleet/units/registrator.service` you should be able to verify where the `EnvironmentFile` option is. Make sure it's in the `[Service]` section and not the `[Unit]` section.

You can also run `fleetctl cat registrator.service` and fleet will output the unit file definition. It's possible you submitted the unit, made changes and then didn't destroy the unit before re-submitting it.